# enviar valor de input text a cmd por php

Tags: php, cmd

Que tal hoy estoy solicitando de su orientacion y ayuda

Ya que estoy trabajando en un formulario web el cual se registran varios parametros pero a la vez quiero que en el momento en que se esta realizando el registro se envien 2 parametros a una consola de comandos alguna sugerencia investigue un poco y me tope con `argv` pero no lo entendi del todo como funciona

de antemano gracias

Comment: Leí dos veces la pregunta y, en realidad, no tengo idea de qué es lo que estás intentando hacer o cuál es el problema que estás enfrentando. Quizás incluyendo algo de código se logre entender. Mira [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [ejemplo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hola Alberto, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son.